# Underscore theme submenu is now showing on mobile

Tags: html, wordpress, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am developing responsive wordpress theme using _S plus bootstrap 3 my problem is I am unable to see sub-menu on mobile devices.
How I want to do?
I actually want when use touch menu the child-menu expend under parent menu here is the URL where I am working.
http://hex-technologies.com/hex_demo/mortenpunnerud

Comment: Please post some of your code so we can help better.

Comment: @David.J Wordpress is a dynamic site how I can post all my code here?

Comment: You can show us how you menu is generated, does it use: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu ? Or you can show us what CSS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this style for your sub menu

```
/*For mobile submenu*/
.main-navigation ul ul {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        float:none;
        /* position: relative; */
        top:inherit;
        box-shadow:none;
        height:auto;
        margin:0;

        background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Should I use it in mobile based media query

Comment: my bad. I suggest looking at this lib https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker it creates bootstrap styled menu from wordpress wp_nav. All you have to do is to include this lib and add few lines of the code to the menu.